# Is this bad practice or normal?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, scope, global

Say for example I have two classes.

I know that one way is to pass a pointer to the Foo object in the constructor and then use that inside Object, but is this a good way to approach things?

Is there something else more appropriate?
Thanks.

```
class Object
{
private: //etc

public:
    void doStuff()
    {
        //access the foo object (x) created in main.
    }
};

class Foo
{
private: //etc

public:
    void function()
    {
        Object * obj = new Object();
        obj->doStuff();
    }
};


int main(int args, char**argv)
{
    Foo * x = new Foo();
    x->function();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use inheritance?

Comment: What are you trying to do? All I see is your main, creating a Foo instance, then calling a function. In that function you create and Object instance and then calling a function on that. What is the question?

Comment: "one way is" --- one way to do what? "to approach things" --- what kind of things? In addition, leaking memory is certainly a very bad practice.

Comment: "Bad practice" and "normal" are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you have to do.
If your doStuff() method must know the content of the given object you can't use this way. Otherwise, if you, like in the example you post, your doStuff method has just to create an object for performing an internal operation you may use this approach.

Generally, there is not a better or a worse way of operating. It always depends.

An example.
Your doStuff method needs something from the external in order to do something:

```
class Foo
{
private: //etc

public:
    void function(Object* obj)
    {
        obj->doStuffWithTheGivenObject();
    }
};
}
```

Your doStuff method needs nothing from external:
    class Foo
    {
    private: //etc

```
public:
    void function()
    {
        Object* obj = new Object();
        obj->doStuffModifyingTheGivenObject();
        this->doStuffOnThisFooObjectWithTheJustCreatedObject(obj);
    }
};
}
```

In the second case your Foo object does not need an Object, because it can independetly create an object by itself for using it internally.
In the first case, instead, it is waiting for an Object because it uses that one for doing something.

The difference stays in: "Do I need an object or I can create that internally?"

Comment: "If your doStuff() method must know the content of the given object you can't use this way."                                                                                                                                   ---=-=-= What do you suggest then?

Comment: Well, yes - that's what I meant by passing a pointer. So my assumptions were correct after all. That's all I wanted to clear up - thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It might help here to know what "Foo" and "Object" actually are. If "Object" actually is "Fruit" and "Foo" is an "Apple" than inheritance makes sense. Alternatively if "Object" represents some sort of stream and "Foo" represents a class that depends on the stream, then what you are doing makes sense. Its all going to depend on what you are trying to accomplish here.